# VBA YesNoCancel not working as expected

Tags: vba

I have the following code and the `YesNoCancel` options don't do anything.  What am I doing wrong please?

```
Option Explicit

Sub wwb()

    'lists each book that's OPEN
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Workbook, wd As Workbook
    Set wd = ThisWorkbook
         MsgBox wd.Name
    Dim output As Integer
    Dim msgValue
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name = wd.Name Then
            MsgBox "The destination WorkBook is :" & wd.Name
        Else
            output = MsgBox("Is " & wb.Name & " your source file to import data?", vbYesNoCancel, "Please confirm source file")
                If msgValue = vbYes Then
                    MsgBox "test yes"
                ElseIf msgValue = vbNo Then
                    MsgBox "test No"
                ElseIf msgValue = vbCancel Then
                    MsgBox "Test cancel"
                End If
        End If
    Next wb

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't have a `set` for `wb`. Who is `wb` ?

Comment: vb are all open workbooks and only store temp names in the for loop, as defined by: For Each wb In Application.Workbooks

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `output` instead of `msgValue`

```
output = MsgBox("Is " & wb.Name & " your source file to import data?", vbYesNoCancel, "Please confirm source file")
        If output = vbYes Then
            MsgBox "test yes"
        ElseIf output = vbNo Then
            MsgBox "test No"
        ElseIf output = vbCancel Then
            MsgBox "Test cancel"
        End If
```

Comment: New this was pretty obvious, many thanks Paul, works like a charm